# How to to loop over function with permutations of parameters?

Tags: python

I have a function `f(x,y)` for which `f(x,y) != f(y,x)`.

I would like to generalise the following for any `n`:

n=1: `C = A`
n=2: `C = f(A,B) + f(B,A)`
n=3: `C = f(A,f(B,B)) + f(B,f(A,B)) + f(B,f(B,A))`
n=4: `C = f(A,f(B,f(B,B)) + f(B,f(A,f(B,B)) + f(B,f(B,f(A,B)) + f(B,f(B,f(B,A))`

The pattern is:

- There are `n` terms.
- Each term has `n-1` calls to `f()`.
- Every term is composed of all `B`s except for one `A` in each position.

Is these a simple way to perform this so I can write a function that computes `C` for any `n` (given also a `A` and `B`)? i.e. `C = general(A, B, n)`

Comment: Have you written any code to solution this? If so, can you please share the code?

Comment: I have written it by hand using an if statement for each case of n if n == 1: ... n==2 ect... This is shown in the question. I have looked at various functions in itertools, but none seem to help.

Comment: for n=3, should it also have f(B,f(A,A)) ? And for n=4, why only the ones you selected. What is the logic to pick the sequence

Comment: @JoeFerndz looks like the pattern is "every term should be composed of all `B`s except for one `A`"

Comment: Yeah you are right, I'll edit for clarity.

Comment: It is 1 A in each term only, in each position.

Comment: Are you looking for a string or a function call?

Comment: @JoeFerndz In my case, A B and C are large sparse csr matrices, and f is the kron function.

Comment: I have shared a string concat solution. Later tonight I will work on an actual function call that can be implemented. I was working on a function call solution while I saw you accept the string function solution. Please clarify in the question what you are looking for (string concat) or function call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Repeatedly combining the results of a binary function is often called "folding" or "reducing", and it's implemented in Python with `functools.reduce` (or just `reduce` in Python 2). There are two possible fold directions: left fold, which given `f` and `[a, b, c, d, e]` would return `f(f(f(f(a, b), c), d), e)`, and right fold, which would produce `f(a, f(b, f(c, f(d, e))))`. By default, `functools.reduce` implements left fold, but it can be turned into right fold by swapping the arguments to the reduced function and reversing the list to be reduced.

To solve your problem, we don't need to reverse the list. We just need to generate it in the correct order. In fact, we don't really need a list, since `reduce` will work just fine with an iterator. For example, this simple iterator:

```py
def oneAatK(A, B, k, n):
    """Returns a generator which produces n values, all of them
       B except for the one at index -(k+1)
    """
    return (A if i + k == n - 1 else B for i in range(n))

# Using this function for f makes the results more visible.
>>> f = lambda a,b: str(a)+str(b)

>>> [* oneAatK('a', 'b', 0, 6) ]
['b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a']
>>> [* oneAatK('a', 'b', 2, 6) ]
['b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b']

def rfoldrev(f, riter):
    """Right folds f on the reverse of the sequence produced by riter"""
    return reduce(lambda acc,val:f(val, acc), riter) 

>>> rfoldrev(f, oneAatK('a', 'b', 0, 6))
'abbbbb'
>>> rfoldrev(f, oneAatK('a', 'b', 2, 6))
'bbabbb'
```

With that, we can generate the individual terms which you want to sum:

```py
# This import is only needed if using Python 3
from functools import reduce
def gen(f, A, B, n):
    return (rfoldrev(f, oneAatK(A, B, k, n))
            for k in range(n))

>>> [* gen(f, 'a', 'b', 6) ]
['abbbbb', 'babbbb', 'bbabbb', 'bbbabb', 'bbbbab', 'bbbbba']
```

Since those are strings, you can't sum them with `sum`, which you could do if `f` returned a number. But you can use `reduce` to combine them with a different binary function:

```py
>>> reduce(lambda acc,v:f"{acc}+{v}", gen(f, 'a', 'b', 6))
'abbbbb+babbbb+bbabbb+bbbabb+bbbbab+bbbbba'
```

Comment: This solves the problem perfectly. Very clear explanation, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a string to be produced that shows as per your output, here's a simpler way to do it.

Here's the explanation of the solution.

Line 1: `y = [B* i + A + B* (n-(i+1)) for i in range(n)]`
Create a string of `'B'` for n positions while replacing ith position with a `A`

Line 2: `if len(y) == 1: return y[0]`
If the output is just a single value, then return just that value

Line 3: `else: return ' + '.join('f('+'f('.join(list(i)[:-2] + [i[-2:]]) + ')'*(len(i)-1) for i in y)`
If the output is a set of Bs with A, then join them as `f(` stripping each character from the list one char at a time leaving the last two chars alone. Those will be combined as a separate set. All of these will be closed with `)` for n-1 times.

The full code is as shown below.

```
def general(A, B, n):
    y = [B* i + A + B* (n-(i+1)) for i in range(n)]
    if len(y) == 1: 
        return y[0]
    else:
        return ' + '.join('f('+'f('.join(list(i)[:-2] + [i[-2:]]) + ')'*(len(i)-1) for i in y)

print ('Usecase one')
print (general ('A','B',1))

print ('Usecase two')

print (general ('A','B',2))

print ('Usecase three')
print (general ('A','B',3))

print ('Usecase four')
print (general ('A','B',4))

print ('Usecase five')
print (general ('A','B',5))
```

The output of this will be:

```
Usecase one
A
Usecase two
f(AB) + f(BA)
Usecase three
f(Af(BB)) + f(Bf(AB)) + f(Bf(BA))
Usecase four
f(Af(Bf(BB))) + f(Bf(Af(BB))) + f(Bf(Bf(AB))) + f(Bf(Bf(BA)))
Usecase five
f(Af(Bf(Bf(BB)))) + f(Bf(Af(Bf(BB)))) + f(Bf(Bf(Af(BB)))) + f(Bf(Bf(Bf(AB)))) + f(Bf(Bf(Bf(BA))))
```